# Is it possible to set 'dummy phone number' in Android? (root or not root)

Tags: android, phone-number, android-permissions, telephonymanager

I know telephonymanager and  .getLine1Number() and get my phone number.

but I want to set dummy phone number in My NEXUS7(2012) WIFI

so I will pass through Another Android app verification (because App wants phone number)

my nexus is rooted

**is it possible to set dummy Phone number? (wifi tablet, or anything else)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android framework has no standard way of setting a "dummy phone number". All telephony emulation needs to happen in the [RIL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_Interface_Layer).